# Why to use "newInstance()" instead of the keyword "new" in kotlin to create xmlPullParserFactory?

Tags: android, kotlin

Why should I use newInstance() instead of new keyword to create XmlPullParserFactory 
and by the way why to create XmlPullParserFactory, I know that the factory pattern is used when you have muliple subclasses to create and you don't know which one until the runtime so we use the factory class to deal with it

```
val factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
factory.isNamespaceAware = true
val xpp = factory.newPullParser()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a design decision. Looking at the [implementation of XMLPullParserFactory](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/9edf43dfcc35c761d97eb9156ac4254152ddbc55/xml/src/main/java/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory.java), it doesn't really matter right now, but if at any point the implementation changes, your code might stop working and have strange side effects.

Since the constructor is protected, you should not be able to use the new keyword anyway.

Hope this clears things up

Answer (score 1):

There is no `new` keyword in Kotlin.

And the `newInstance` function is just a static method on the class `XmlPullParserFactory` for creating an instance of `XmlPullParser`, presumably to select the correct concrete type of `XmlPullParser` based on some configuration you provide to the `XmlPullParserFactory`.